# WCF HTTP file stream service and how to handle file changes

Tags: .net, wcf, http, streaming

What is the proper way of implementig this?
I have a simple WCF **http** streaming service. My OperationContract returns a Stream object:

```
return File.OpenRead(path);
```

But how to handle local file changes on server side? How do I replace current file? 
I can't because some clients are downloading it...

Should I change the behavior and return partial content? But how?

Comment: I'm looking for a implementation of Range Retrieval Requests. See
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as scalable as you need but you could open the file OpenShare = LockWrite

[OpenShare Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.openshare.aspx)

Then to update the file you would need to wait for the lock to clear.